# installed package "sf" disappeared after failing to install package "stars", and unable to re-install all the dependencies

Tags: r-sf, r-package, install.packages

I am running R version 3.6.3 with RStudio 1.3.1093 on MacOS 10.13.6.

I installed and have been using the package "sf" for a while, and everything functions just fine.
But after I tried to install the package "stars" and it failed (unfortunately I didn't save the error message), the following warning appeared:
[image]

When I called the package, an error appeared:

```
> library(sf)
Error in library(sf) : there is no package called ‘sf’
```

So I tried to install the package again by `install.packages("sf")` and by loading "sf_1.0-15.tar.gz" from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html, both attempts failed:

```
> install.packages("sf")
also installing the dependencies ‘wk’, ‘s2’, ‘units’

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘wk’ ‘s2’ ‘units’ ‘sf’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source packages ‘wk’, ‘s2’, ‘units’, ‘sf’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/wk_0.9.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1039442 bytes (1015 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 1015 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/s2_1.1.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2376936 bytes (2.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/units_0.8-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 247974 bytes (242 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 242 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sf_1.0-15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3485450 bytes (3.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘wk’ ...
** package ‘wk’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c bbox-handler.c -o bbox-handler.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c count-handler.c -o count-handler.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c debug-filter.c -o debug-filter.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c flatten-filter.c -o flatten-filter.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-crc.c -o handle-crc.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-rct.c -o handle-rct.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-sfc.c -o handle-sfc.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-wkb.c -o handle-wkb.o
clang++ -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-wkt.cpp -o handle-wkt.o
In file included from handle-wkt.cpp:11:
In file included from ./internal/buffered-reader.hpp:5:
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:80:3: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
  constexpr explicit parse_options(chars_format fmt = chars_format::general,
  ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:80:13: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
  constexpr explicit parse_options(chars_format fmt = chars_format::general,
  ~~~~~~~~~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:111:59: warning: use of enumeration in a nested name specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
                             T &value, chars_format fmt = chars_format::general)  noexcept;
                                                          ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:111:81: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
                             T &value, chars_format fmt = chars_format::general)  noexcept;
                                                                                ^
                                                                                ;
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:111:83: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
                             T &value, chars_format fmt = chars_format::general)  noexcept;
                                                                                  ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:118:71: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
                                      T &value, parse_options options)  noexcept;
                                                                      ^
                                                                      ;
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:118:73: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
                                      T &value, parse_options options)  noexcept;
                                                                        ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:217:20: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
  char running_diff{0};
                   ^
                   ;
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:236:3: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
  constexpr size_t len() const noexcept {
  ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:236:19: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
  constexpr size_t len() const noexcept {
                  ^
                  ;
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:324:12: error: function definition does not declare parameters
  uint64_t mantissa{0};
           ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:325:11: error: function definition does not declare parameters
  int32_t power2{0}; // a negative value indicates an invalid result
          ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:326:25: warning: defaulted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  adjusted_mantissa() = default;
                        ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:328:26: error: no member named 'mantissa' in 'fast_float::adjusted_mantissa'
    return mantissa == o.mantissa && power2 == o.power2;
                       ~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:328:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mantissa'
    return mantissa == o.mantissa && power2 == o.power2;
           ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:328:50: error: no member named 'power2' in 'fast_float::adjusted_mantissa'
    return mantissa == o.mantissa && power2 == o.power2;
                                               ~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:328:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'power2'
    return mantissa == o.mantissa && power2 == o.power2;
                                     ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:331:26: error: no member named 'mantissa' in 'fast_float::adjusted_mantissa'
    return mantissa != o.mantissa || power2 != o.power2;
                       ~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:331:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mantissa'
    return mantissa != o.mantissa || power2 != o.power2;
           ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:331:50: error: no member named 'power2' in 'fast_float::adjusted_mantissa'
    return mantissa != o.mantissa || power2 != o.power2;
                                               ~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:331:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'power2'
    return mantissa != o.mantissa || power2 != o.power2;
                                     ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [handle-wkt.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘wk’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/wk’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘wk’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘units’ ...
** package ‘units’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
configure: units: 0.8-5
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
checking whether clang++ accepts -g... yes
checking for clang++ option to enable C++11 features... none needed
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for _Bool... no
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... no
checking for error_at_line... no
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking for XML_ParserCreate in -lexpat... yes
checking for udunits2.h... no
checking for udunits2/udunits2.h... no
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/xq/3h4582853bx56xs6nkzh65c40000gn/T/RtmpJXBgPv/R.INSTALL5f814c9f34b2/units':
configure: error: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Configuration failed because libudunits2.so was not found. Try installing:
    * deb: libudunits2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, ...)
    * rpm: udunits2-devel (Fedora, EPEL, ...)
    * brew: udunits (OSX)
  If udunits2 is already installed in a non-standard location, use:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib'
  if the library was not found, and/or:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
  if the header was not found, replacing paths with appropriate values.
  You can alternatively set UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIBS manually.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘units’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/units’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/units’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘wk’ is not available for package ‘s2’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/s2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘s2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘s2’ is not available for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/xq/3h4582853bx56xs6nkzh65c40000gn/T/RtmpDdn7rS/downloaded_packages’
```

I can still call "units" with `library(units)`

But when I try to install the other two dependencies ("wk", "s2"), they both failed. Here is the error I got when installing the package "wk":

```
> install.packages("wk")
```

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘wk’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source package ‘wk’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/wk_0.9.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1039442 bytes (1015 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 1015 KB

* installing *source* package ‘wk’ ...
** package ‘wk’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c bbox-handler.c -o bbox-handler.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c count-handler.c -o count-handler.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c debug-filter.c -o debug-filter.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c flatten-filter.c -o flatten-filter.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-crc.c -o handle-crc.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-rct.c -o handle-rct.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-sfc.c -o handle-sfc.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-wkb.c -o handle-wkb.o
clang++ -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-wkt.cpp -o handle-wkt.o
In file included from handle-wkt.cpp:11:
In file included from ./internal/buffered-reader.hpp:5:
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:80:3: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
  constexpr explicit parse_options(chars_format fmt = chars_format::general,
  ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:80:13: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
  constexpr explicit parse_options(chars_format fmt = chars_format::general,
  ~~~~~~~~~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:111:59: warning: use of enumeration in a nested name specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
                             T &value, chars_format fmt = chars_format::general)  noexcept;
                                                          ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:111:81: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
                             T &value, chars_format fmt = chars_format::general)  noexcept;
                                                                                ^
                                                                                ;
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:111:83: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
                             T &value, chars_format fmt = chars_format::general)  noexcept;
                                                                                  ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:118:71: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
                                      T &value, parse_options options)  noexcept;
                                                                      ^
                                                                      ;
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:118:73: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
                                      T &value, parse_options options)  noexcept;
                                                                        ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:217:20: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
  char running_diff{0};
                   ^
                   ;
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:236:3: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
  constexpr size_t len() const noexcept {
  ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:236:19: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
  constexpr size_t len() const noexcept {
                  ^
                  ;
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:324:12: error: function definition does not declare parameters
  uint64_t mantissa{0};
           ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:325:11: error: function definition does not declare parameters
  int32_t power2{0}; // a negative value indicates an invalid result
          ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:326:25: warning: defaulted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  adjusted_mantissa() = default;
                        ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:328:26: error: no member named 'mantissa' in 'fast_float::adjusted_mantissa'
    return mantissa == o.mantissa && power2 == o.power2;
                       ~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:328:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mantissa'
    return mantissa == o.mantissa && power2 == o.power2;
           ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:328:50: error: no member named 'power2' in 'fast_float::adjusted_mantissa'
    return mantissa == o.mantissa && power2 == o.power2;
                                               ~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:328:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'power2'
    return mantissa == o.mantissa && power2 == o.power2;
                                     ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:331:26: error: no member named 'mantissa' in 'fast_float::adjusted_mantissa'
    return mantissa != o.mantissa || power2 != o.power2;
                       ~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:331:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mantissa'
    return mantissa != o.mantissa || power2 != o.power2;
           ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:331:50: error: no member named 'power2' in 'fast_float::adjusted_mantissa'
    return mantissa != o.mantissa || power2 != o.power2;
                                               ~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:331:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'power2'
    return mantissa != o.mantissa || power2 != o.power2;
                                     ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [handle-wkt.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘wk’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/wk’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘wk’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/xq/3h4582853bx56xs6nkzh65c40000gn/T/RtmpDdn7rS/downloaded_packages’
```

I also tried to install the dependencies by downloading and loading the tar.gz files (s2_1.1.6.tar.gz & wk_0.9.1.tar.gz), that also failed:

```
> install.packages("~/Documents/R/Package tgz/wk_0.9.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
* installing *source* package ‘wk’ ...
** package ‘wk’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c bbox-handler.c -o bbox-handler.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c count-handler.c -o count-handler.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c debug-filter.c -o debug-filter.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c flatten-filter.c -o flatten-filter.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-crc.c -o handle-crc.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-rct.c -o handle-rct.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-sfc.c -o handle-sfc.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-wkb.c -o handle-wkb.o
clang++ -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c handle-wkt.cpp -o handle-wkt.o
In file included from handle-wkt.cpp:11:
In file included from ./internal/buffered-reader.hpp:5:
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:80:3: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
  constexpr explicit parse_options(chars_format fmt = chars_format::general,
  ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:80:13: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
  constexpr explicit parse_options(chars_format fmt = chars_format::general,
  ~~~~~~~~~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:111:59: warning: use of enumeration in a nested name specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
                             T &value, chars_format fmt = chars_format::general)  noexcept;
                                                          ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:111:81: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
                             T &value, chars_format fmt = chars_format::general)  noexcept;
                                                                                ^
                                                                                ;
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:111:83: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
                             T &value, chars_format fmt = chars_format::general)  noexcept;
                                                                                  ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:118:71: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
                                      T &value, parse_options options)  noexcept;
                                                                      ^
                                                                      ;
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:118:73: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
                                      T &value, parse_options options)  noexcept;
                                                                        ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:217:20: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
  char running_diff{0};
                   ^
                   ;
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:236:3: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
  constexpr size_t len() const noexcept {
  ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:236:19: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
  constexpr size_t len() const noexcept {
                  ^
                  ;
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:324:12: error: function definition does not declare parameters
  uint64_t mantissa{0};
           ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:325:11: error: function definition does not declare parameters
  int32_t power2{0}; // a negative value indicates an invalid result
          ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:326:25: warning: defaulted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  adjusted_mantissa() = default;
                        ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:328:26: error: no member named 'mantissa' in 'fast_float::adjusted_mantissa'
    return mantissa == o.mantissa && power2 == o.power2;
                       ~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:328:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mantissa'
    return mantissa == o.mantissa && power2 == o.power2;
           ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:328:50: error: no member named 'power2' in 'fast_float::adjusted_mantissa'
    return mantissa == o.mantissa && power2 == o.power2;
                                               ~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:328:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'power2'
    return mantissa == o.mantissa && power2 == o.power2;
                                     ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:331:26: error: no member named 'mantissa' in 'fast_float::adjusted_mantissa'
    return mantissa != o.mantissa || power2 != o.power2;
                       ~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:331:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mantissa'
    return mantissa != o.mantissa || power2 != o.power2;
           ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:331:50: error: no member named 'power2' in 'fast_float::adjusted_mantissa'
    return mantissa != o.mantissa || power2 != o.power2;
                                               ~ ^
./internal/fast_float/fast_float.h:331:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'power2'
    return mantissa != o.mantissa || power2 != o.power2;
                                     ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [handle-wkt.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘wk’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/wk’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/Suen/Documents/R/Package tgz/wk_0.9.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I could not figure out what caused this issue other than the failed installation of the package "stars" (I could be completely wrong). I would appreciate it if someone could give me some advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to update to the released version of R (now 4.3.3) so that you can then install binary packages for `sf` and its dependencies.